# broadcast message keeps coming into service after quit and re-start the activity which starts the service

Tags: android, service, broadcast

I'm working on a Android APP. There's a main activity and a service. The service is started by calling startService(intent) in main activity. and it would be running in background no matter the activity is running or not. After the activity is created, it will send broadcast message to service to query some status. The first time of the running is okay, both activity and service initiated correctly. But I get an issue that when I quit the activity and restart it, the service will keep receiving the query message like the activity is sending it repeatedly. But I confirmed the sending code in activity was only executed once. Anyone have idea where the messages comes from?

the codes in main activity onCreate method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.v("debug", "Main.onCreate");

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, PingService.class);
        startService(intent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PingService.ACTION_QUERY);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And below are codes in service

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(PingService.ACTION_QUERY)) {
            Log.v("debug", "PingService.receiver.onReceive: ACTION_QUERY");

        //the program keeps coming here
        }
    }
 };

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v("debug", "PingService.onCreate");

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("pingd",
            android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    //handlers
    serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
    daemonHandler = new DaemonHandler(thread.getLooper());

        //register broadcast receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(PingService.ACTION_ADD);
        filter.addAction(PingService.ACTION_QUERY);
        filter.setPriority(999);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


        instance = this;
}
```

Comment: Sir, please post ur relevant portions of your code so we check it,

Comment: I added some codes. In main.onCreate, I have tried not start service everytime but only if it not exist. And it still doesn't work. Also tried sending the ACTION_QUERY message later when some button clicked. but still not work neither.